# Non database transactions in a dopwizard/jdbi webservice environment

Tags: java, web-services, transactions, dropwizard

Suppose I want to perform some operations which are not database related together, i.e; if any one fails, undo all. Is there a standard way of doing such things since this should be a common requirement? I am specifically talking about a dropwizard/jdbi java web service. General suggestions are welcome too. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of operations are we talking about here? How would the application know what to do on a failure scenario if these are non DB transactions?

Comment: Say I am invalidating a map/cache of objects after an update, so here first operation is the db update and the second one is cache invalidation, I may want that if the cache invalidation failed then rollback the db update also.

Comment: I doubt there is a generic solution available for this as the rollback would be specific to the operation (e.g. the rollback for the cache invalidation would be to put the object back into the cache). You could write a custom solution for this that keeps the operations being performed and all the information required for the rollback of each of them, then handle the rollback logic. You could also make all the requests go through some kind of facade that would handle the DAO call and subsequent logic, rollback, etc, but there could some duplicate code for the different resources.